# Makefile specific to directory structure

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile my project using a makefile. I'm new to makefiles so forgive my ignorance. The problem I'm running into is that I would like the output command to build all of the .o files but If I run it as such it will not build the .o files and instead will try to compile all .o files in the /obj directory.

How would I compile all .o file rules in the output rule?

```
The directory structure for this project is:
recipe_book
|-GFX         (source directory)
|-PageManager (source directory)
|-Pages       (source directory)
|-main        (source directory)
|-obj         (.o files directory)
|-out         (application output)
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -g

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

G++ = g++ -std=c++17 $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS)

#Source Directories:
GFX := GFX
PAGE_MANAGER := PageManager
PAGES := Pages

#Object Directory:
OBJ := obj

# Complile the objects into the executable
output: main/main.cpp main/main.hpp $(OBJ)/*.o
    $(G++) main/main.cpp $(OBJ)/*.o -o out/recipe_book.out

#make all object files
#'.' turns them into macros?
#GFX
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(GFX)/%.cpp $(GFX)/%.hpp
    $(G++) -I$(GFX) -c $< -o $@

#PageManager
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(PAGE_MANAGER)/%.cpp $(PAGE_MANAGER)/%.hpp
    $(G++) -I$(PAGE_MANAGER) -c $< -o $@

#Pages
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(PAGES)/%.cpp $(PAGES)/%.hpp
    $(G++) -I$(PAGES) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm out/*.out obj/*.o
```

Comment: Do you have to use a make file? Other build systems are easier to learn/use

Comment: I'm using make just to keep things simple... It works If I list out all of the .o files generated so I feel using make will work just fine if I can figure out this last part. Also I'm developing this for multiple platforms (Linux, Rasperry Pi, Windows)

Comment: You want the object files (`.o`) in the working directory? If so, then I think changing `OBJ := obj` to `OBJ := .` will suffice.

Comment: Oh sorry I may not have made myself all that clear. I want the .o files to be in the obj directory. The problem is that when I build it it doesn't build any .o files. I would like to have the output compile everything out of the obj directory into the out directory just to keep things neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
output: main/main.cpp main/main.hpp $(OBJ)/*.o
```

cannot work correctly as written.  What does this do?  It tells make, the target `output` (which, by the way, you never actually create: this rule creates a totally different file `out/recipe_book.out`, but leave that aside for now) depends on the files `main/main.cpp`, `main/main.hpp`, and the expansion of the glob expression `obj/*.o`.  So, make looks up the files that match the glob expression `obj/*.o`, which is all the object files *that already exist*.

If all the object files already exist, then all of them will be linked.  If you haven't created any object files, then none of them will be found (just like if you run `ls obj/*.o` no files are found) and so none of them will be linked.

You have to list the explicit set of object files that you want t link here.  You can't use glob expressions to find them.

You can use glob expressions to find the *source* files, which always (presumably) exist, then convert those into the object files.  Maybe something like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(GFX)/*.cpp $(PAGE_MANAGER)/*.cpp $(PAGES)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJ)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES))))

output: main/main.cpp main/main.hpp $(OBJECTS)
```

(and by the way, you really should use the real file name for this target not `output`: in make, all non-phony targets should always have the name of the actual file they create).

Answer (score 0):

Your `output` target has, as prerequisites, `$(OBJ)/*.o`.

But, when nothing's been built yet, that wildcard expands to nothing!

You're going to need to list the objects that are required for the final link of the project, e.g.

```
output: main/main.cpp main/main.hpp $(OBJ)/GFX.o $(OBJ)/PageManager.o $(OBJ)/Pages.o
```

This will then trigger the creation of those files (via compilation) where needed.

You can streamline it by putting `GFX PageManager Pages` in a variable, then performing a substitution to prepend `$(OBJ)/` to each one and to append `.o` to each one.

As an aside, I'd probably roll `main` into this, rather than treating it specially.

Comment: Oops, didn't realise this was an old tab that has had an answer in the interim  Ah well